# Unable to cast Session UserID to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to get the current user form the session UserId but get this error. 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Trinity.Models.tblUser'.'

Where I createthe Session Id:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authorise(tblUser user)
{
    using (var db = new TrinityEntities())
    {
        var userEmail = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Email);
        var userPassword = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Password == user.Password);

        //check login incorrect
        if (userEmail == null || userPassword == null)
        {
            ViewBag.LoginIncorrect = "E-mail or Password not correct";
            return View("Index", user);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserID"] = userEmail.Id;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Where I get the error:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    var currentUser = (Models.tblUser) Session["UserID"];

    using (var db = new Models.ChatContext())
    {
        ViewBag.allUsers = db.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName != currentUser.FirstName).ToList();
    }

    ViewBag.currentUser = currentUser;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: So you put in an `int` and you expect that to come out as a `tblUser` on the other side?

Comment: Im trying to get the UserId of the current user to have him not show up as a possible person to chat to.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment.

Comment: _"So you put in an int and you expect that to come out as a tblUser"_     Well I expect it to get the user by the Sessions UserID @PatrickHofman

Comment: But you put in a number instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only storing the ID (a number) but when you read it back you're expecting the whole user - that's not going to work. Instead you'll need to use the ID to reload the user:

```
var currentUserId = Session["UserID"];
var user = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
```